# Is there another notation for a characteristic of a domain of a measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, notation

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $E\in\Sigma$.

In measure theory language, one can prove that $\int_E f d\mu = \int \chi_E f d\mu$.

Here, $\chi_E$ is *not* a function, but it merely means that $\chi_E f$ is a function sharing every value of $f$ on $E$ and having $0$ on $E^c$.

This notation disturbs me since i sometimes make mistake viewing this as a characteristic function.

I think $f_E$ is much suitable in this case. Is there a wide-using notation rather than $\chi_E$?

Comment: What are your assumptions for $f$? Positive? Measurable? a.e. finite?

Comment: @Ronald nonnegative measurable function whose codomain is $[0,\infty]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration on a measurable subsst $E$ of a measurable space $X$ is usually defined to be $\int_Ef:=\int\chi_Ef$ where $\chi_E$ is the function equal to $1$ on $E$ and $0$ on $E^{c}$.
Here $\chi_Ef$ is just multiplication of functions which is equal to $f_E$ using your notation.

It would be good to mention that the integration on $E$ can also be defined to be the integration on $E$ viewed as a measurable space with the measure being the restriction to measurable subsets of $E$ in this case we can prove that $\int_Ef=\int\chi_Ef$ where here $\chi_Ef$ denotes multiplication of functions.